# how can I add labels to g.raphael pie chart

Tags: text, label, raphael, graphael, pie-chart

I want to add labels to a g.raphael pie chart to display with each segment. I can't find any code to do this and haven't been able to figure it out on my own - can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you go with the example code from raphael:
http://raphaeljs.com/pie.html

The label is added in this line:

```
 txt = paper.text(cx + (r + delta + 55) * Math.cos(-popangle * rad),
 cy + (r + delta + 25) * Math.sin(-popangle * rad), 
 labels[j]).attr({fill: bcolor, stroke: "none", opacity: 0, "font-size": 20});
```